# Garage door not properly sealing on top

Tags: garage, garage-door

I noticed a rather large gap between the garage door and the frame opening (see light coming through in picture below).

Any ideas on how to adjust the existing top hinge to push door tighter onto the frame?  I saw online a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7QuiQDICrkA) but the hinge I have is not the same as that shown.

Do I need to replace the existing hinge with some other hinge model?

[image: Sunlight coming through the top left of the garage door, lights are OFF inside]
[image: top left hinge close-up]

Answer (score 4):

Loosen those two bolts on the top bracket and see if you can pull that bracket down further into the curved rail while pushing the door against the frame. If you can, then tighten up the two bolts and that should help solve the problem. If that doesn't work, you'll need to put shims, washers between the bracket and door to force the door closer to the frame. Don't forget to check all your weather stripping that's usually attached to the frame, some of it could have deteriorated and fallen off.

Comment: Yes, those long slots are your adjustment mechanism. By lowering the top set of wheels you force into a closer portion of the track. The lower bolt will need to be repositioned.

Comment: @isherwood  Good catch on the lower bolt.  I thought the hole above it was part of the slot but zooming in, I can see that it's not.

Comment: @JACK, yes, I hadn't noticed isherwood's note about the lower bold but noticed after your suggestion.  Will give it a try this weekend, I guess i would have to fully remove the lower bolt and, perhaps, the repositioning may allow me to use the single hold in between the slits to fit that one in there...  thank you for the quick response! will definitely try this weekend and revert

Comment: It is much easier to adjust the bracket when the door is open they you are not fighting the weight of the door. Use a pencil and mark both the door and metal before adjusting. That way you can go back if needed. My first choice would be to replace the weather stripping as it appears to be a few years old. Do not be surprised if the weather stripping solves both light leaks.

Comment: How are you not "fighting the weight", @Gil, when the door is open and hanging horizontally? Removing the bolts from the hinge would then allow gravity to kick in and pull the corner of the door down. Also, how do you know how far to push the door to get it closed properly if it's open? With the door closed, you loosen the top bolt, remove the bottom, push the door against the wall to seal the gap, tighten the top bolt & drill a new hole for the lower one (in the middle of its adjustment range for future proofing).

Comment: You can slide the bracket without removing the bolts, they are typically slotted to allow this. For me I slightly loosen the bolts and tap the hinge in the direction I want, tighten it and  close to see if I got it. I put a pencil mark to see how much I have moved it.